# Get rid of "pointer assignment might outlive the pointer target" in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a code similar to this:

```
module mod
    implicit none
    real, pointer :: p1=>null(), p2=>null()
end module mod

program target_lifetime
    use mod
    implicit none
    real, target  :: t(2)

    p1 => t(1)
    p2 => t(2)

    nullify( p1, p2 )

end program target_lifetime
```

When I compile this code with
`gfortran -Wall target_lifetime.f90`
I obtain

```
target_lifetime.f90:14:4:

   14 |     p1 => t(1)
      |    1
Warning: Pointer at (1) in pointer assignment might outlive the pointer target [-Wtarget-lifetime]
target_lifetime.f90:15:4:

   15 |     p2 => t(2)
      |    1
Warning: Pointer at (1) in pointer assignment might outlive the pointer target [-Wtarget-lifetime]
```

What is the correct way to code this in order to get rid of the warning?

Comment: By not using pointers? Seriously, pointers are rarely a good idea in Fortran and best avoided if at all possible. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The code I'm workin on is a much larger code (~5000 lines), written in F77 that I recently translated to F90. There were some `equivalence` statements that I converted into pointers. It works now with pointers and removing them could potentially introduce bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning here is clearly bogus because of the lifetime of the main program variable is until the end of the program and the `t` array is implicitly `save`.

There is not much you can do. You can open a bug with GCC and ask whether it is possible to change the behaviour here.

I can see that it could be triggered by internally implementing the `__MAIN` (or some other name) procedure as a subroutine (actually a funciton in C or GIMPLE) and then treating the variables as local variables in some checks. But then the standard still says that the variables in the main program are `save` implicitly.

Comment: This is what I was hoping to read. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir is likely correct that this a side-effect of the implicit save of `t1` and `t2`.  Fortunately, the warning is generated from only one place within the gfortran source code.  This means that you can easily suppress the warnings with this patch.

```
diff --git a/gcc/fortran/expr.cc b/gcc/fortran/expr.cc
index 290ddf360c8..543d4e24286 100644
--- a/gcc/fortran/expr.cc
+++ b/gcc/fortran/expr.cc
@@ -25,6 +25,7 @@ along with GCC; see the file COPYING3.  If not see
 #include "gfortran.h"
 #include "arith.h"
 #include "match.h"
+#include "parse.h"
 #include "target-memory.h" /* for gfc_convert_boz */
 #include "constructor.h"
 #include "tree.h"
@@ -4523,7 +4524,10 @@ gfc_check_pointer_assign (gfc_expr *lvalue, gfc_expr *rvalue,
        break;
      }
 
-      if (warn)
+      if (warn
+     && (gfc_current_state () != COMP_PROGRAM)
+     && (!(gfc_current_state () == COMP_NONE
+           && !gfc_state_stack->previous)))
    gfc_warning (OPT_Wtarget_lifetime,
             "Pointer at %L in pointer assignment might outlive the "
             "pointer target", &lvalue->where);
```